# How to create a new dataFrame based on some column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has a column Flag whose values are either True or False. I want to create a new dataframe whose column Flag's values must be all True.

```
df = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
      'Age':['12', '23', '25', '16'],
      'Flag':[True, False, False, True]}
```

I want get a new df whose Flags are True, and also drop this Flag column:

```
df = {'Name':['Tom', 'jack'],
       'Age':['12', '16']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use boolean masking and `drop()` method:

```
resultdf=df[df['Flag']==True].drop(columns=['Flag'])
```

OR

You can also use `where()` method

```
resultdf=df.where(df['Flag']==True).dropna().drop(columns='Flag')
```

Output:

```
print(resultdf)

    Name    Age
0   Tom     12
3   jack    16
```

If you want index starting from 0 then just chain `reset_index()` method:

```
resultdf=df[df['Flag']==True].drop(columns=['Flag']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

OR

```
resultdf=df.where(df['Flag']==True).dropna().drop(columns='Flag').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
print(resultdf)

    Name    Age
0   Tom     12
1   jack    16
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `boolean` column, so compare by `True` is not necessary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

You can select some columns only by list use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[df['Flag'], ['Name','Age']]
```

Or use and remove `Flag` use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html):

```
df1 = df[df.pop('Flag')]
```

Or delete Flag after selecting add [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df1 = df[df['Flag']].drop('Flag', axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df1)
   Name Age
0   Tom  12
3  jack  16
```

Answer (score 1):

First make it a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
  'Age':['12', '23', '25', '16'],
  'Flag':[True, False, False, True]})
```

Then you can do as below:

```
df.loc[[0,3] ,["Name","Age"]]
```

Result will be like:

```
    Name    Age
0   Tom     12
3   jack    16
```